# Why is Field Level Security at the object-level presented as "Visible / Read-only" instead of "read / edit"?

Tags: profile, fls, read-only, edit

If you access FLS settings for a given profile, it lists all the "edit" and "read" permissions for all fields in any object.  If accessing the FLS settings from the object by clicking the "Field Level Security" button it lists these same permissions (I believe, and this is in part why I'm asking this question ... I'm not sure) under the headings of "Visible" instead of "Read" and "Read-Only" instead of Edit (which is the opposite of Edit)?  Also, of course, it does this for all profiles for the field selected (instead of all fields for the profile selected).

Is that correct?  If so, is there a reason they don't just use "read" and "edit" for both FLS interfaces?  Is it just to screw with nOOBs like myself?

Comment: This is a pretty awesome question, but I don't think anyone will have an answer, since it'd take probably two salesforce engineers (minimum) to answer this.

Answer (score 0):

I can only assume by the text in the help and training that is was because one came before the other and *insert your own why here*.

> Field permissions specify the access level for each field in an
>   object. In permission sets and the enhanced profile user interface,
>   the setting **labels differ** from those in the **original** profile user
>   interface and in field-level security pages for customizing fields

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_profiles_field_perms.htm

Again, only assumption but the use of the word "Original" indicates that they decided to change the labels to make it *insert your own reason here*. Maybe some behind the scenes reasons that we do not care about but SF does....

It could have been easier to just make the change in the newer features than to change them in both places and update all of the documentation? Maybe??

Who knows for sure but at least this proves it is documented that they know and acknowledge the difference in the labels